# Rspec extremely slow, one file needs 4 second to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using `spring (1.1.3)`  and `Rails 4.1.6`

But as you can see, the execute time is really slow ?

How to profile the bottleneck ? Thanks

```
% bundle exec bin/rspec spec/models/tool/cvt/streaming_verification_spec.rb
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of PDF was here
"show combination"
.

Finished in 0.00119 seconds (files took 4.42 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

### Gem about rspec

```
  * guard-rspec (4.3.1)
  * rspec (3.1.0)
  * rspec-core (3.1.5)
  * rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
  * rspec-mocks (3.1.2)
  * rspec-rails (3.1.0)
  * rspec-support (3.1.1)
```

Comment: why don't you try zeus?

Comment: anything new here I tried `zeus` and `spring` but no luck